# What's the difference between these two addAction declaration?

Tags: ios, swift

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
        //Cancel Action
    }))
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign out",
                                  style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                                  handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in
                                    //Sign out action
    }))
```

The second declaration has this `handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!)` extra part, so I was wondering is it necessary and what does it do?
Source: https://medium.com/swift-india/uialertcontroller-in-swift-22f3c5b1dd68

Comment: The type annotation is just syntactic sugar and not needed. And the trailing exclamation mark is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of compiling this

```
handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in
```

is same as

```
handler: { _ in
```

But if you don't use the alert action variable inside the callback for some reason like this

```
handler: { alertAction in
    print(alertAction.title)  // e.x 
}).
```

Then doing `handler: { _ in`  is better than doing `handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in`

**TLDR**

- Generally a callback is given in case developer needs to do some business when the alert action is clicked if this business needs anything from the alertAction then below 2 options that can be written

  ```
  1-    handler: { alertAction  in // recommended 
  2-    handler: { (alertAction:UIAlertAction)  in // too long
  ```
- If there is a business a part from the alert action  then below 2 options that can be written

  ```
  1-    handler: { _  in     // short and better
  2-    handler: { (_:UIAlertAction)  in // worst ever
  ```
- Also if you do nothing when clicking the alert action supply nil

  ```
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign out",
                              style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
                              handler:nil)
  ```

Comment: side note - most people will use a trailing closure: `alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .default) { _ in ... })`

Comment: @Sulthan off course it's the shortest way to get rid of callback parameter name

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be difference between:

```
block: { parameter in ... }
block: { (parameter) in ... }
block: { (parameter: TypeOfTheParameter) in ... }
```

If you don't use the var, you can replace it with "_", so you have;

```
block: { _ in ... }
block: { (_) in ... }
block: { (_: TypeOfTheParameter) in ... }
```

Usually, there is no need to explicitly specify the class of the parameter.
Some generic methods might prefer though.

Applied to your sample:

```
block: handler
parameter: _
TypeOfTheParameter: UIAlertAction
```

The `!` shouldn't be useful in modern Swift (and might even trigger an warning or compiler error). Your tutorial is from 2018, Swift has changed since then.